# Change video url for MPMoviePlayerController instance rather than allocating new one

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have an `MPMoviePlayerController` named `myMoviePlayer`; I allocate and initialize it when my app loads:

```
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:[movieName uppercaseString] ofType:@"mov" inDirectory:@"Videos"];

if(moviePath)
{
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];

    myMoviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [**myUI.view** setFrame:CGRectMake(80, 80, 600, 350)];
    [self.view addSubview:myMoviePlayer.view];
    myMoviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
}
```

There are two views in my app named `imageView` and `videoView`. I need to hide `myMoviePlayer` in `imageView` and display it again when my UI view is `videoView`.

Each time I show a movie, `movieName` will be different.

Right now, I am allocating and initializing `myVideoPlayer` each time my view changes to the movie view. Is it possible to set a new video url to `myMoviePlayer` without allocating it again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
[myMoviePlayer setContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aMovieUrl]];
```

Just set the [contentURL property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2) of the [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instance.

Comment: problem when i am setting video player at second time .it shows only a movie player with full black screen

Comment: @Sharmain well it's the normal way to start a new video, have a look at the links. Does the video actually start? I think it needs some time for buffering.

Comment: showing only video.it will play only when i click play button

Comment: [myVideoplayer.view setHidden:YES];this is the method iam using to hide my videoplayer

Comment: it hiding my video player but setting a new url at next time it will display a black screen

Comment: @Sharmain just show the video player again. However there is some kind of bug with the MPMoviePlayerController: if it gets covered completely it'll crash in most cases, so I am not sure if hiding is just another DON'T DO.

Comment: @Sharmain & @Nick; Nick is correct in stating that the MPMoviePlayerController does not like to lose its surface while playing (or being in pause mode). If the player is actually not playing (stopped), this should not be an issue.

Comment: @Sharmain You are saying it shows a black screen on the second video - how about the audio, can you hear any sound?

Answer (score 7):

Sharmain i got your problem...
you need to set the contentURL and then call Play method of mpmovieplayercontroller:

```
[myPlayer setContentURL:xyz];
[myPlayer play];
```

enjoy..!!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];   
self.myPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
self.myPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 124, 768, 900); 
self.myPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
self.myPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
self.myPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
self.myPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
self.myPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
self.myPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
[self.view addSubview:myPlayer.view];

[myPlayer setContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[myPlayer play];
```